# Recommend a Git GUI client for Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: git, user-interface, ubuntu, client

the last thread made on this subject was 2009 so i'm hoping people can tell me what they are currently using.

I'm new to Linux and don't know much about the terminal and such yet, but I am able to use git via command line if needed.  Primarily I run windows 7 and have been using Git Extensions / Gitbash.

If anyone has any recommendations on something similar that is easy to install or at least has good instructions for Ubuntu please paste a link or write up a quick description.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend gitg . It shows a clear revision tree and is much fancier than gitk.

```
$sudo apt-get install gitg
$cd path/to/gitrepo
$gitg
```

Comment: Thank you, out of the 3 so far this seems to be on par with what I'm using in Gitextensions for Windows

Comment: If you find a satisfying answer please upvote and/or accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't use GUI for most Git operations but when I wanna see git tree or preview file edits then I use Giggle. Once I've tried to set up Meld as mergetool and difftool but then when want to see only `git diff any_file` with only a few diffs inside it was running whole Meld, that was annoying so I've forgotten about it and use only standard diff with vimdiff.

Answer (score 1):

You could try qgit.

Most important features: browse revisions history, view patch content and changed files, graphically follow different development branches.

Download-Site: http://sourceforge.net/projects/qgit/

Website: http://digilander.libero.it/mcostalba/

or `sudo apt-get install qgit`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aptana it's a IDE but have a git GUI
http://aptana.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are used to GIT Extensions, you can try to run it on Ubuntu: http://jeremykentc.blogspot.co.il/2012/09/git-extensions-240-on-ubuntu-1204.html